# Setting the last plot in the middle with facet_wrap

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, facet, facet-wrap

I am trying to create some multiplots with facet_wrap. However I am not sure if is the right approach for my graph. Here is a short reproducible example:

```
 ggplot(airquality, aes(x = Day, y = Temp)) +
  facet_wrap(~Month) + 
  geom_line()
```

This produces this plot here:

[image]

Is it possible to "center" the two plots in the 2nd row with the facet_wrap approach ?

Note, that I don't want to reorder the plots, I just want to Center the 2nd row

Comment: You're Right. I added a short example. Note, that I dont want to reorder the plots. I want to center them

Comment: I have un-downvoted. now unfortunately both @Jaap and I had misunderstood your question and marked it as a duplicate. Please ask a new question, because otherwise no one will pay attention to this question. I wonder, however, what you would like to achieve with 'centering'. I don't think that this is in the intention of the ggplot developers, and also contradicts a bit the 'facet style' - you would need the labelled x-axis on both facet rows. Therefore, probably best to use one of the plot combining packages such as cowplot. Or simply use `facet_grid`

Comment: The question is open again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@Tjebo's suggestion of using `cowplot` will work:

```
p <- ggplot(mapping = aes(x = Day, y = Temp)) +
  facet_wrap(~Month) + 
  geom_line()

cowplot::plot_grid(
  p %+% subset(airquality, Month < 8),
  p %+% subset(airquality, Month > 7),
  nrow = 2
)
```

[image]

Comment: Didn't know that this would work `p %+% subset(airquality, Month < 8)`. (+1)

Comment: The cowplot solution is very nice ! Just one question. Is there way to assign one jont axis title. In particular to have one "Temp" in the middle instead of two

Comment: `?cowplot::draw_label`

Answer (score 7):

You might also consider the function `set_panel_size` from the [`egg`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/egg/) package which lets you set the panel size (width, height) of multiple plots to an absolute measurement, see [this vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/egg/vignettes/Overview.html) for more details.

Using Axeman's code to create the plots

```
library(egg)
library(gridExtra)
p <- ggplot(mapping = aes(x = Day, y = Temp)) +
  facet_wrap(~Month) + 
  geom_line()

p1 <- p %+% subset(airquality, Month < 8) + labs(x = NULL)
p2 <- p %+% subset(airquality, Month > 7)
```

Now arrange the plots using `grid.arrange` after specifying the panel sizes

```
grid.arrange(grobs = lapply(
  list(p1, p2),
  set_panel_size,
  width = unit(5, "cm"),
  height = unit(4, "cm")
))
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, this might very well be the better option, depending on the use case.

Answer (score 4):

And yet another option to achieve the desired result would the `ggh4x` package which via `ggh4x::facet_manual` adds some flexibility to position the facets via the `design` argument:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggh4x)

base <- ggplot(airquality, aes(x = Day, y = Temp)) +
  geom_line()

design <- c(
"
AABBCC
#DDEE#
"
)

base + ggh4x::facet_manual(~Month, design = design)
```

[image]

```r
design <- c(
"
AABBCC
DDDEEE
"
)
base + ggh4x::facet_manual(~Month, design = design)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

And just in case anyone wants to know how to do it from scratch in grid...

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(grid)

vps <- c("top_left", "top_mid", "top_right", "bottom_left", "bottom_right")

main_vp  <- vpTree(viewport(name = "main"), vpList(
              viewport(x = 1/6, y = 0.75, width = 1/3, height = 0.5, name = vps[1]),
              viewport(x = 3/6, y = 0.75, width = 1/3, height = 0.5, name = vps[2]),
              viewport(x = 5/6, y = 0.75, width = 1/3, height = 0.5, name = vps[3]),
              viewport(x = 1/3, y = 0.25, width = 1/3, height = 0.5, name = vps[4]),
              viewport(x = 2/3, y = 0.25, width = 1/3, height = 0.5, name = vps[5])))

grid.newpage()
pushViewport(main_vp)

plots <- lapply(1:5, function(i){ 
  seekViewport(vps[i])
  invisible(grid.draw(ggplotGrob(
    
    ggplot(filter(airquality, Month == levels(as.factor(airquality$Month))[i]), 
           mapping = aes(Day, Temp)) + 
      geom_line() + 
      facet_grid(.~Month)
    
)))})
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-07-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>